# Mountain Lion - Rails - Symbol not found: _rb_Digest_MD5_Finish (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, osx-mountain-lion

I am running Mountain Lion. After installing apple-gcc-4.2 using Macports (with a symlink to /usr/bin/gcc-4.2), rvm, ruby 1.9.3 and gem install rails, I received the error "Symbol not found: _rb_Digest_MD5_Finish (LoadError) Referenced from: /Users/userid/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p362/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin12.2.0/digest/md5.bundle" error when running 'rails new testapp'.  I don't see this discussed anywhere and am completely stumped on how to proceed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Stephen

Answer (score 2):

Check if `C_INCLUDE_PATH` is set. `env | grep C_INCLUDE_PATH`. If it is, remove it from your environment, and then rebuild Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Install [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki/X112.7.4) and try reinstall Ruby, and Rails

It will solve the 'darwin' problems